# Intent filter for many extensions

Tags: android

I would like to write an application which deals with many kind of source files. *("bsh", "c", "cc", "cpp", "cs", "csh", "cyc", "cv", "htm", "html", "java", "js", "m", "mxml", "perl", "pl", "pm", "py", "rb", "sh","xhtml", "xml", "xsl")*
Is this the only way to set a long intent filter or do you know a more elegant way?

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.bsh" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.c" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cpp" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cs" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.csh" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cyc" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cv" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.htm" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.html" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.java" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.js" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.m" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mxml" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.perl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pl" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pm" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.py" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.rb" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.sh" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xhtml" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xsl" />
            <data android:host="*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I have two issues with the code above:

1. Long and ugly
2. I have to store the filetypes in two places, because I have to reach the list from code too.

I have two idea:
 1. I should extend the intent filter dynamically from code (where the list of the extensions is stored.)
 2. I should store in the list in the array.xml and this way I can reach it from code and I may build the intent filter from this file.

Do you have any other new idea, or any idea how to make it work the solutions above?

Answer (score 1):

> I should add the intent filters dynamically from code (where the list of the extensions is stored

That is not possible.

> I should store in the list in the array.xml and this way I can reach it from code and I may build the intent filters from this file

That is also not possible.

> Do you have any other new idea

You might be able to store the `android:pathPattern` values as individual string resources. Whether that really helps you is debatable.